# In which European countries do ATMs impose an extra surcharge for withdrawals?

Tags: banking, fees, cash, withdrawal, atm

Usually you pay a fee (if any) set by your bank for withdrawing money with your Visa/MC card from ATMs other than those your bank owns, but some ATMs charge the customer an extra fee on top of that independent of the fee charged by the cardholders bank.

However, such ATMs only exist in some countries; I have never seen them in Germany, Poland, or the Czech Republic, for example.

Countries where such ATMs with extra fees are known to exist include:

- United Kingdom
- United States
- Australia
- Thailand

Are there any other countries on the European continent, besides the United Kingdom, where such ATMs with surcharges exist?

Comment: I remember being charged a fee for ATM usage in France, but I don't know if its a common practice, I was there on a business for several days and just used ATM once. I know that in Israel some ATM's charge fees.

Comment: @littleadv I am not sure you understand I am asking only about fees charged by the ATM operator on top of the usual fee of your bank - so in result you'd be charged two fees - one by your bank (unless the bank charges no fees for usage of foreign ATMs), and a second fee by the ATM. Was that the case in France?

Comment: yes, that's what I'm talking about, fees charged by the ATM operator itself, **in addition** to the fees charged by my bank for the out-of-network ATM usage.

Comment: You might have better luck with this question on http://travel.stackexchange.com/ (thought it is on-topic here too)

Comment: Voting to close. There are quite a few countries, and networks. The fees is a complex function of type of card, Issuing Bank, Card Type [Visa/mater/etc] and the ATM company, tie-up etc.

Answer (score 2):

ATM surcharges exist based on the preference of the ATM owner, not the country where it sits.   I believe that any country *could* have these ATMs if the owner so desired.

Answer (score -1):

> Do ATMs impose an extra surcharge for withdrawals?

In France, that depends on whether the ATM is owned by a French bank.

https://wise.com/us/blog/atms-in-france:

> French banks don’t charge foreigners any fees to use ATMs. Privately-owned ATMs, on the other hand, do charge expensive fees and should be avoided. You can recognise these machines by the absence of any identifiable bank branding.